# Effective downloading of several xml data sources

Tags: android, xml, json, download

Im working on a app that show a list of `places` with travel time and weather information for that `place` . My problem is that when i have a list of about 12 (and growing) `places` it takes quite some time for the app to download all the information.

For each place the process is the following :

1. Connect to Google Directions api and get distance from user location to that `place` (download a JSON file and parse it to get distance)
2. Connect to YR.no and download a (big) xml file with weather information about that place. Parse that xml file and return the weather information for that plce
3. Add the place to a listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a backend which will do all this tasks and return the final JSON data.

Comment: As a server you meen ?